# Tritone as a passing note

Tags: theory, technique, scales, intervals, consonance-and-dissonance

Can a tritone be used as a passing note? (say in key of C, going from note C to G).

Comment: Any note can be used as a passing note. Very often you'd come across a D or D7 chord as a secondary dominant for the G major chord. In this case the F# is the third of that chord.

Comment: What about ["Once Upon a Time in the West"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyvzfyqYm_s)?

Comment: I believe The Simpsons' theme song employees this device.  I'm not sure that we would refer to this as a passing tone though, as a passing tone is usually step-wise motion.

Comment: Classical harmony allows an unprepared appogiatura.  Whether you class it as a "passing note" is merely a matter of terminology.   Modern useage certainly includes unprepared non-scale tones.  Though modern theory can get strangely pedentic over notes that don't fit the prevailing chord/scale!

Comment: We don't allow song search or itemized lists here, so I've edited your question a bit.  Matt and Laurence, I would consider turning your comments into answers.

Comment: Silly implementation of a silly rule.  The examples given from West Side Story help a lot in understanding the question.

Comment: @Laurence Payne - I'd have quoted 'Maria' anyway, but good point, as the OP only used that as an addendum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Maria* from West Side Story, uses exactly that for the first line (not sure if it's in that key, but hey). The underlying harmony is root, the first note is also root, and the tritone is the second, leading to a 5th on the third note. It sounds like it may modulate, but as Matt says, but it doesn't. The fact that the tritone is a semitone from the target is good, as resolutions often move that small distance.

Comment: The whole score of "West Side Story" (except "I Feel Pretty", which was a late addition) features that interval.  Mostly it's used melodically, to give a "cool jazz" flavour.  But look at the very last few bars of the score, where a C major triad with an F# bass note underlines the final tragedy.

Answer (score 0):

Riffs and melodies moving quickly from #4 to 5 comprise a huge part of blues and jazz. You'll be hard pressed to find music from those genres that doesn't make ample us of that melodic transition - #4 is one of the traditonal [**blue notes.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_note) - that's a tritone from the root moving towards the 5 - a building block of the blues. So the answer is **Yes.**